# Json return results plot on flotchart

Tags: ajax, flot

I have a json returning 3 values, time, point1 and point 2 within an array object. In my success when data is returned, i split the data to two arrays (array1) and (array2).

```
data[0] <- time
data[1] <- value 1
data[2] <- value 2
```

Reason being, I would like to plot array1 = (data[0],data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQVx0.png)) and array2 = (data[0],data[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBxNM.png)).

When plotting the above, i get all the results correctly, but cannot scroll or zoom out, it plots everything in one go, squashed.

When i plot the data in datasets it doesn't allow for scrolling and zooming in, using the jquery.flot.time.js for example gives errors.

```
 from the ajax success
success: function(result) {
// populate dialog window with graph
data = $.evalJSON(result);
var count = Object.keys(data).length;
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
res.push(data[i]);
}
if(data.length > 0){
plot_diag();
}
```

and than in the plot_diag function

```
function plot_diag()
{
diag_plot = $.plot($("#flot-diagram"), res)
}
```

would the be a way that can limit number of points/range on flot diagram and on zoom-out display next batch from the array?

Thanks in advance

[image: rendered chart, the pan, zoom out.. controls not working, this example has 1242 entry arrays]
[image: values =, time and point 1 and point: so my array 1 [has data.o and data1] and array2 [data.0 and data.2]]

[image: total arrays pulled for this chart]

Comment: Can you build a stack snippet or jsfiddle that shows the problem? The code in the question should be ok.

Comment: Hi Raidiri, got distracted going to the js fillde asap, so the plot does happen, per chart i get a variety of values for example 1242 entries pulling from the database.